# Infinite groups with 2 automorphism orbits

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations, automorphism-groups

A group $G$ is called a *$k$-orbit* group if its automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(G)$ acting naturally on $G$ has precisely $k$ orbits. The only finite 2-orbit groups are the elementary abelian groups $(C_p)^n$ where $p$ is prime and $n\geqslant1$.

**Question 1:** Is it hopeless to classify the infinite 2-orbit groups?

The automorphism group of the additive group $D^+$ of a division algebra $D$ is transitive on the set $D^\times=D\setminus\{0\}$: if $a,b\in D^\times$, then $a^\alpha=b$ where $\alpha\in{\rm Aut}(D^+)$ sayisfies $x^\alpha=xa^{-1}b$. (Taking $D=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ gives the elementary abelian example.) However, Corollary 2 on page 212 of
"P.M. Cohn, The embedding of firs in skew fields. *Proc. London Math. Soc.* (3) **23** (1971), 193–213"
shows that there is a division algebra $D$ such that the multiplicative group $D^\times$ has 2 conjugacy classes (1 non-trivial). Hence $D^\times$ is a non-abelian 2-orbit group. More generally, HNN extensions show that there exist infinite groups $G$ which I would guess do not equal $D^\times$ for any $D$, with precisely 2 conjugacy classes, see "G. Higman, B.H. Neumann, H. Neumann, Embedding theorems for groups. *J. London Math. Soc.* **24** (1949), 247–254". (Cohn's construction mimics HNN's.) I would suppose that there are many other rather different examples of 2-orbit groups; however, I am unaware of different constructions.

Edit: The abelian example is better framed as a (nonzero) vector space $V$ over a field $F$: clearly $GL(V/F)\leqslant{\rm Aut}(V)$ has 2 orbits $\{0\}$ and $V\setminus\{0\}$ as Rickard noted. Viewing $V$ as a vector space over the prime field of $F$ gives YCor's comment.

Comment: The sentence after Question 1 has a few typos, and I'm not quite sure that I understand what you meant to write. In particular, when you say "The additive group", do you mean "The automorphism group of the additive group"? So are you just pointing out that the additive group of a division algebra is a 2-orbit group? The reason that I think this might not be what you meant is that then it's not clear why you mentioned division algebras, as the additive group of any nonzero vector space is a 2-orbit group.

Comment: Easy fact: An abelian group satisfies this property (2 orbits under Aut) iff it is a simple module over its automorphism group, iff it is a nonzero vector space over either $\mathbf{Q}$ or $\mathbf{F}_p$ for some prime $p$ (no need to go through division algebras to see this). Nonabelian examples are perfect groups and have no proper subgroup of finite index.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thank you. I corrected the typos.

Comment: You can start with any torsion-free group and embed it in an infinite group with exactly two conjugacy classes using a countably-infinite chain of HNN extensions. Given how flexible this construction is, I think there is no hope for any reasonable classification.

Comment: I should add that this class includes no infinite locally finite group. Indeed, this should then be a infinite $p$-group (of exponent $p$), but on the other hand it is known that no infinite locally finite simple group is locally solvable (see e.g. Corollary 3.5 [here](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/meierfra/Classnotes/LFG/LFG.pdf) — *Locally finite, simple groups* by Ulrich Meierfrankenfeld).

Comment: I think that the task of classification of finitely generated groups with 2 conjugacy classes is already completely intractable: Denis Osin's construction of a f. g. group with 2 conjugacy classes depends on a lot of arbitrary choices.

Comment: On the other hand, there are quite beautiful constructions by J. Berrick of _universal_ embeddings of groups into perfect groups. It is called "binate tower", and is a special case of HNN tower mentioned by Moishe Cohan earlier.

Comment: The locally compact abelian groups $G$ where ${\rm Aut}(G)$ has at most 2 topological orbits on $G$ are described in Theorem 2.13 of
Markus Stroppel, Locally compact groups with few orbits under automorphisms. Topology Proc. 26 (2001/02), no. 2, 819–842.